# Rendering Problems: Android Studio 1.2.1.1 and Gradle 1.2.3

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, rendering

I updated android studio to latest version which is "1.2.1.1" with gradle 1.2.3..But I have problem with My projects and new projects..
all Layouts files can't show preview because of this problem:

```
Rendering problems

The following classes could not be found: android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout
```

I found solution for it which change the theme to:

```
Base.Theme.Appcompat
```

But now It doesn't show any Custom view or even Appcompat views. It gives me this error:

```
The following classes could not be found: - android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
The following classes could not be found: - CustomView.VoiceView (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project.
```

I tried also to change rendering version to 21 instead of 22..
It doesn't work..Clean and rebuild don't do anything..
Thanks in advance.

Update [Add style.xml]:
My style code is :

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_blue_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/light_blue_700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/light_ornage_500</item>
    </style>



    <style name="RevealOrange" parent="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_blue_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/light_ornage_700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/light_ornage_500</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: show your styles.xml

Comment: @Nilesh Update with style.xml code..Please check it.

Comment: try to use noActionbar theme

Comment: Removed "Base" and added no "NoActionBar" but the same problem..

Comment: I have posted answer please check and revert

Comment: Same problem, same Android Studio and gradle version. In my case any other "gradle-imported" classes got rendering problems.

Answer (score -1):

This theme worked for me try this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_darker_color</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: mmm. It doesn't work :( ... Which version of android studio and gradle do you have??

Answer (score -1):

Probably it's problem with Android Studio building a project with target equals or greater than 21 and minSdk its very low, like 10. Create a values-v21/styles just like below.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_darker_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```